# Where getFeatureInfo Request is built on cesium?

Tags: angular, typescript, cesiumjs, getfeatureinfo

I am using cesium with angular. I need to know where is built the request url for GetFeatureInfo in cesium but i cannot find it.
For the context, what I want to do is display featureInfo on click on the map. But the request sent is using x and y parameters for coordinate and what I would like is replace them by i and j.
Moreover, I would like to get bbox information present in this same request to display them.
If someone could help me !
Thank you !

Comment: Are you asking in WebMapServiceImageryProvider's getFeatureInfo?

Comment: Yes ! I am using it for getMap, but it does not work for getFeatureInfo, in fact the request is sent with params x and y instead of i and j. So, I tried to build the request alone, but I am blocked with the bbox and the i and j coordinate. I do not know where to find it. Or maybe if you know how to replace x,y by i,j ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request is actually made in UrlTemplateImageryProvider.js's function pickFeatures.

[image]

This is a call stack screenshot in [this sample](https://github.com/3DGISKing/CesiumJsSamples/tree/master/ImageryLayer/WMS).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, should i change name param x and y for i and j in this file ?

Comment: It is strange, I guess it is not coming from `buildPickFeatureResource()` because i commented this function and the request is still sent with all the params

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, First of all, thank you @ZhefengJin !

Due to your answer, I have checked the `UrlTemplateImageryProvider.js`, but the answer was not there. Nevertheless, It guides me to `WebMapServiceImageryProvider.js`. There, I noticed that x and y coordinate are assigned to `x={i} and y={j}` in `pickFeatureParams`.
I tried to add new param in this var but it did not work, I still do not understand why.

But I have tried to had my new param in my `getFeatureInfoParameters` using the same value, thinking that it will be passed in `webMapServiceImageryProvider` too and be assigned the same way.

And it works for me.